# How to check if the .sig file is correct ?

Tags: ssl, openssl, digital-signature

I issued the following commands to create a signature for a file (linux kernel) :

1. openssl req -newkey rsa -keyout codesign.key -out codesign.req
2. openssl ca -config ca.cnf -extensions codesigning -in codesign.req -out codesign.crt
3. openssl cms -sign -binary -noattr -in vmlinuz -signer codesign.crt -inkey codesign.key -certfile ca.crt -outform DER -out vmlinuz.sig

The ca.cnf file is for my own private CA infrastructure and it has digitalSignature key usage extension and the codeSigning extended key usage extension enalbed.

How can i verify that the vmlinuz.sig is the signature of the vmlinuz ??

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: As a dev, I sometimes have to play with this stuff (verifying downloads, for example, or creating downloadable files). While this is not a programming-specific question, it is relevant to development. And, I know you can verify .sig files with GnuPG or PGP - but is it possible with openssl?

Comment: Hi @user_3526 , Yes we can verify signatures using the cms utility.  Please refer to this link for answer:   [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1063064/how-to-check-if-the-sig-file-is-correct)